# Want to show details of Apache virtual host in another server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, vhosts

We have many virtual hosts on our apache server i.e.
www.vhost1.com which resides in:
C:\Apache\htdocs\web\www-vhost1-com

and 
www.vhost2.com which resides in:
C:\Apache\htdocs\web\www-vhost2-com

When we develop our site images show properties 
http://www.vhost1.com/images/image1.jpg

What we want to do is show the image properties in the format:
http://www.server.com/d/www.vhost1.com/images/image1.jpg

I am not sure how to do this in the Apache config files.

Thanks
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use mod_alias and map the /d/www.vhost1.com/ path to the C:\Apache\htdocs\web\www-vhost1-com\ directory. This needs to be done in the www.server.com virtual host configuration section.

```
Alias /d/www.vhost1.com/ C:\Apache\htdocs\web\www-vhost1-com\
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer 
I did the following:

Alias /test1/ "c:/Apache2/htdocs/web/" 
<Directory "c:/Apache2/htdocs/web/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

I have client folders setup as 

c:/Apache2/htdocs/web/www-host1-com-au etc

So at the moment I did the following:

https://apache_url/test1/www-host1-com-au/thumbnailsmall/image.jpg

Where I want to do the following:
https://apache_url/test1/www.host1.com.au/thumbnailsmall/image.jpg
or even
https://apache_url/test1/www.host1.com.au/image.jpg